# Storage engine for large amounts of constantly inserted data which should be available instantly

Tags: mysql, sql, database, architecture

Our server (several Java applications on Debian) handles incoming data (GNSS observations) that should be:

1. immediately (delay <200ms) delivered to other applications,
2. stored for further use.

Sometimes (several times a day maybe) about million of archived records will be fetched from the database. Record size is about 12 double precision fields + timestamp and some ids. There are no UPDATEs; DELETEs are very rare but massive. Incoming flow is up to hundred records per second. So I had to choose storage engine for this data.

I tried using MySQL (InnoDB). One application inserts, others constantly check last record id and if it is updated, fetch new records. This part works fine. But I've met following issues:

1. Records are quite large (about 200-240 bytes per record).
2. Fetching million of archived records is unacceptable slow (tens of minutes or more).

File-based storage will work just fine (since there are no inserts in the middle of DB and selections are mostly like 'WHERE ID=1 AND TIME BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000', but there are other problems:

1. Looking for new data might be not so easy.
2. Other data like logs and configs are stored in same database and I prefer to have one database for everything.

Can you advice some suitable database engine (SQL preferred, but not necessary)? Maybe it is possible to fine-tune MySQL to reduce record size and fetch time for continious strips of data?

MongoDB is not acceptable since DB size is limited on 32-bit machines. Any engine that does not provide quick access for recently inserted data is not acceptable too.

Comment: Determining whether data is "recently inserted" is a function of any logic you implement, not a function of the platform you implement it on.

Comment: With MongoDB, you can use sharding to extend data size over 4 GB. And why do you use 32bit machines anyway?

Comment: @Dems I've heard that some NoSQL engines provide weak consistency; I am worried about that. If two applications on single machine connected to DB, one inserts and commits, then second should notice these changes ASAP

Comment: @fge We want to avoid 64-bit OS requirement in this software, this could cause some problems. About sharding: Is it possible to configure automatical sharding (like when the DB size is reaching limit or periodically) with transparent access to all records? Also, MongoDB is document-oriented, won't be the records too large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no getting around how long it takes to load millions of records from disk. Your 32-bit requirement means you are limited in how much RAM you can use for memory based data structures. But, if you want to use MySQL, you may be able to get good performance using multiple table types.

If you need really fast non-blocking inserts. You can use the black hole table type and replication. The server where the inserts occur has a black hole table type that replicates to another server where the table is Innodb or MyISAM.

Since you don't do UPDATEs, I think MyISAM would be better than Innodb in this scenario. You can use the MERGE table type for MyISAM (not available for Innodb). Not sure what your data set is like, but you could have 1 table per day (hour, week?), your MERGE table would then be a superset of those tables. Assuming you want to delete old data by day, just redeclare the MERGE table to not include the old tables. This action is instantaneous. Dropping old tables is also extremely fast.

To check for new data, you can look at "todays" table directly rather than going through the MERGE table.

Comment: I think this might be what I need. I decided not to use MyISAM because it is non-transactional, but missed idea of different engines for different tables. For log and config tables I'll leave InnoDB because they are not actively used, and I'll try MyISAM for observations table. The merging might help too: data is collected simultaneously from different sources, so if I insert it into one table it probably will become interleaved and selecting strips for exactly one source could be slow because of that. But if I create subtable for each source and merge them this might solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com/) storage engine for MySQL. It's free for up to 50GB of user data, and it's pricing model isn't terrible, making it a great choice for storing large amounts of data.

It's got higher insert speed compared to InnoDB and MyISAM and scales much better as the dataset grows (InnoDB tends to deteriorate once working dataset doesn't fit the RAM making its performance dependant on the I/O of the HDD subsystem).

It's also ACID compliant and supports multiple clustered indexes (which would be a great choice for massive DELETEs you're planning to do). Also, hot schema changes are supported (ALTER TABLE doesn't lock the tables, and changes are quick on huge tables - I'm talking gigabyte-sized tables being altered in mere seconds).

From my personal use, I experienced about 5 - 10 times less disk usage due to TokuDB's compression, and it's much, much faster than MyISAM or InnoDB. 
Even though it sounds like I'm trying to advertise this product - I'm not, it's just simply amazing since you can use monolithic data-store without expensive scaling plans like partitioning across nodes to scale the writes.

Comment: This is very interesting option! I'll definitely check it.

Comment: Here is some info on how TokuDB performs vs InnoDB. [link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/05/07/benchmarking-percona-server-tokudb-vs-innodb/)